# Android animate to singleTask

Tags: android, animation, transition

I am making an app with multiple tabs (without the tabview). One takes a long time to load so I made a singletask of it. Now it only has to load once what saves a lot of time.

Only in the onCreate I define the transition I want:
`overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);`

Only the onCreate is never called again, i tried to put it on top of the onResume and onStart but that didn't helped either.

The problem now is that the animation becomes the default animation which differs a lot on different devices.

Does anyone know a way to change this? I tried calling it after the startActivity method with no succes either.

If anyone has a solution to stop the loadtime then it is also okey.
The load time goes to making multiple listview in a swipeview (jason fry). This listview contains around 90 imageviews each, most of them are the same image.

Thanks for any thoughts, ideas or solutions in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the **finish()** method of your activity.
In the overridden method, after calling super.finish() - call **overridePendingTransition()** with your favorite transition (if you want no transition - define a transition that does nothing, with duration 0).

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling that in the `onNewIntent()` method.  That should be called when you try to launch the `Activity` a second time.